# Add opensearch xml to stackexchange.com

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search, stackexchange.com

For all stackexchange sites I've seen so far, there's an opensearch xml file, like here on meta:

```
<link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml"
      title="Meta Stack Overflow" href="/opensearch.xml">
```

This is missing for stackexchange.com. Since the cross site search is a very useful feature, I think it makes sense to include an opensearch xml there too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Done. Stackexchange.com supports OpenSearch now.